# Flask retrieve element from for loop

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a music app project which I am working on that uses Flask and SQLalchemy to display search results when you search for a given song. At the moment, I am trying to create a "song page" if you will that displays details regarding the specific song selected. My flask for loop is as such:

```
{%for row in result%}

            <li class="product-result">
                <div class="result">
                    <h3 style="width: 60%; font-size: 95%;" class="result_title">{{row.title}}</h3>
                        Similar to {{search}}</h4>
         
                </div>
            </li>
            {%endfor%}
```

I want to store the row.title in some sort of session variable that can be passed to the song details page when the result is clicked. I am not sure the proper course of action to do this- hence the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to store the title in session? I recommend that you put a button in the loop along with the id. Then when you click on the detail button it will look for the details based the title id.

Comment: How would I pass the variable via a button?

Answer (score 0):

Instead try the following in your html loop:

```
  <a href="/deatil/{{row.id}}/{{row.title}}/" class="btn btn-danger">Detail</a>
```

and then in your route:

```
 # get a specified post by id
    @post_bp.route('/detail/<int:id>/<title>/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def detail(id, title):
        if request.method =='GET':
            # get comments under specific post
            comment = db.session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.post_id==id).order_by(Comment.id.desc())
            # count comments under specific post
            no_of_comments = db.session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.post_id == id).count()
            # get post under specific id
            post = Post.query.get(id)
            user = User.query.get(post.author_id)
            return render_template('post.html', post=post, user=user, comments = comment, total_comment = no_of_comments)
```

N.B: This is my sample. You can convert to your own.

Comment: Think you can: `no_of_comments = comment.count()`